# Share data between two partial views in tab UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created two tabs using jquery UI, and placed two partial views in the tabs as the below code.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1">
   @Html.Partial("Tab1")    </div>
<div id="tab2">
   @Html.Partial("Tab2")
</div>

</div>
```

How can I share data from Tab2 partial view to Tab1 partial view.

Thanks,
Naren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't**. Directly sharing data between partial views is no good architecture, either. Each partial view should exist for *one* distinct purpose and should not interfere or exchange data with other ones — in fact, `Tab1` shouldn't even know that `Tab2` exists.

However, you could store the data in the `Model` property of the view containing the two partial views and hand that over to each partial view that is rendered:

```
@model SomeModel

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
       @Html.Partial("Tab1", Model)
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
       @Html.Partial("Tab2", Model)
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Our partial view has to create a div with a unique ID for jQuery's .buttonset(). How can the second instance create a different ID without sharing data with the first?

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish, but have you tried using `Guid`s as IDs for the different `div` elements?

Comment: I solved it by externally supplying the partial view with a unique ID. But, of course, a Guid (= large enough random value?) would probably be a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Stylistically I prefer to load not load 2 partials in the same page if the user can only see 1 at a time... I personally prefer to just split them into different views (event if the experience to the user make it look like they're clicking through tabs to get the affect you want)

This prevents partial B from doing something that potentially slows down page load times for partial A, thus slowing down the user experience for no apparent reason.

If you loaded these into 2 different views, then you could use standard action links to move the data across... This is also helpful if you need to navigate directly to a tab (that's not the first one)